# Salary re-negotiation after accepting job offer

Tags: compensation

I accepted a job offer with Company X. However, the process took significantly longer almost a year and my circumstances changed. I got another exciting opportunity with good compensation. I am still interested in the company X but would like to try re-negotiation based on these changes in circumstances. Is it worth trying? What are the risks?

Thanks for your help!

Regards

Comment: Did you already signed the offer letter stating the salary and start date?

Comment: What caused the process to take almost a year?

Answer (score 6):

> Is it worth trying?

Of course. Getting higher salary is always worth trying. You state exactly what you said here. The best to do is getting another offer (with a higher starting salary) in hand and base your negotiation on it.

> What are the risks?

The only risk is losing the offer. They either say OK here is a greater starting salary, or they will just dismiss the offer.

Comment: There is option 3: They think you are a "troublemaker" for renegotiating at this stage. They don't want troublemakers and don't give you the job.

Comment: @Edgar I'm pretty sure that that is already explained in the "What are the risks?" section of this answer.